# Reload not restart of Mariadb on CentOS 7

Tags: centos7, mariadb

Hallo I'm having MariaDB 10 installed on a CentOS 7 and I'm looking for a way to reload a tweaked server.cnf. I'm not looking for a restart as I'm having a script running that takes over a month to complete and it have been running for about 20 days.

I have searched and duckduckgo for days, but haven't found a useful search string to find the solution to this Q.
like countless of other users I've tried

```
systemctl reload mariadb
Failed to reload mariadb.service: Job type reload is not applicable for unit mariadb.service.
```

Does any one know how to just reload the config without restarting?

Comment: You can't find anything because there _isn't_ anything. There is no "reload" functionality.

Comment: Hi Michael :)   not exactly what I was hoping to hear :/   more like an answer on a work around :)

Comment: While it's not possible to reload my.cnf, you can try to change variables themselves. Try `SHOW VARIABLES` and if you can find ones you wanted to tweak there - just use a command like `SET GLOBAL concurrent_insert =  1;` to set them without restarting.

Comment: True :)   completely forgot that :) thx